# How to get the input from the subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python program will will be called by another python program via a subprocess:

The python program is like this:

```
import argparse
import sys
from base64 import b64decode
import json


def set_key(args, **kwargs):
    path = "/tmp/key"
    print(kwargs)
    try:
        with open(path, 'wb') as open_file:
            b = b64decode(kwargs)
            open_file.write(b)
        return Result(True)
    except OSError as e:
        return Result(False)
    return Result(True)

commands_map = {
    "set-key": set_key,
}


def main(sys_argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="a util command"
    )

    parser.add_argument("-N", dest="check_testing", action="store_true",
                        help="check testing")
    parser.add_argument("cmd", choices=sorted(list(commands_map)))

    args, remaining = parser.parse_known_args(sys_argv)
    # Not entirely sure there's much benefit to this check.
    if args.check_testing:
        return 1 if args.testing else 0
    result, vals = commands_map[args.cmd](
                          remaining, testing=args.testing,
                          check_testing=args.check_testing)
    print(json.dumps(vals, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
    return 0 if result else 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

And the caller program is:

```
import subprocess

input = b'{\n  "keys": "l0Pu3TlknxWqTZwDG1yJcjUDGcBH7c8F19fkxeNmBl/2wXQoochlbxLTKhgkzeQNRDvFkQfMBcdlsbcxrrEQX+IydyiLkU5o8Gmhe2JGP56CNPLIefl9WPvLlPQBdvjEWO2UBaBjo2VW3Xsd1Ng+xFSUbP/ls7dso+h5/Ty37Rw="\n}'
cmda = ['python3', 'test.py', 'set-key']

try:
   s = subprocess.run(cmda, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, input=input)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
   print(e.stderr)
```

When I try to execute the call program, it complains the subprocess program kwargs is a dict.

```
b'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "test.py", line 46, in <module>\n    sys.exit(main())\n  File "test.py", line 40, in main\n    check_testing=args.check_testing)\n  File "test.py", line 12, in set_key\n    b = b64decode(kwargs)\n  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/base64.py", line 80, in b64decode\n    s = _bytes_from_decode_data(s)\n  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/base64.py", line 46, in _bytes_from_decode_data\n    "string, not %r" % s.__class__.__name__) from None\nTypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not \'dict\'\n'
```

How can I properly pass the input to the subprocess program so that I can write to a file?

Also, the args and kwargs seems to be empty (I expect it should be taken from the input call from subprocess). Anyone know why they are empty?

Comment: you could format error - `decode()` before print.

Comment: can't you do it without `subprocess` ? `import test` and `test.main()` ?

Comment: after `decode()` rrror shows `argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'dict'` - why do you send it as dictionary if it needs only string? Or maybe you should use `b64decode(kwargs['keys'])` instead of `b64decode(kwargs)`

Comment: when I run your code I get different error `AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'testing'` because you forgot (or removed) `parser.add_argument("testing",...)`. Better put correct code.

Comment: @furas I am sorry I should clarify. I have to use a subprocess as it is how the system works. The test.py is just a code snippet that how the program call my code.

Comment: @furas, I should clarify as well. The problem is I don't see the parameter (from Input) get pass in to the program; The args and kwargs are empty but I am not sure why.

Comment: `input=` sends by `stdin` so in `test.py` you would have to use `sys.stdin.read()` to get it. If you want to send as argument then you would have to put it in `cmda = [..., input]` and then you get it as `remaining` - but you will have to convert it to dict using `json`